# How do I edit a nested array and set changes to a range of cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm able to clear the `backlog` status in the program, and push changes to the `segment = data [x]` array, but I'm unable to get those changes in the cell referenced by `var range = sheet.getRange("E2:J10");`. My issue is specifically in the second if statement of the for loop.

```
// Description:
//The task will be available again after 14 days
//First the program will scan `Task`s to detect backlog tasks
//Then for each task the program will take the current date `cDate` - `dateOfTask` =`diff` (inDays)
//If days past is greater than 14 days, then the task will be set to an empty cell `Task`.setblank 
//Once the cell is empty the task will be available to the algo task manager for prioritization
```

[image]

```
    function myFunction() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
      var range = sheet.getRange("E2:J10"); //debugged // test task on line 9
    //     // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
      //const d = dRange.getValues();
      var cDate = range.getCell(1,6);
      console.log(cDate.getValue());
      var data = range.getValues();
      console.log(data);
    
        //forloop
    
    for (x=0; x<data.length; x++) {
    
    var segment = data[x];
    
    if (segment[1] == "Backlog"){
    
      var now = new Date();
      var dateOfTask = new Date(segment[5]);
      var diff = now - dateOfTask;
      var timeValue = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
      //console.log("Difference in milliseconds: ", diff); // 11140829739   
      console.log("Difference in days: ", timeValue)
    
    //var timeValue = DAYS(cDate, segment[5]);
    
      if(timeValue > 14){
      var refreashBacklog = segment.splice(1,1,"clear contents");
      range.setValue(refreashBacklog.segment);
      Logger.log(segment);
      //ask for help on stackOverflow 
      }
      else{
      continue
      }
    }
    else{
      continue // remember to set a stop at a certain row so it doesn't go to 999
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Below is another version of the code that returned "clear contents" in the intended position of the nested array.

`
  if(timeValue > 14){
  segment.splice(1,1,"here");
  console.log(segment);
  }
`

Comment: You can not subtract Date() objects like this `var diff = now - dateOfTask;`  You can subtract valueOf() and getTime() but be advised these number are in milliseconds since a date in the past.

Comment: I think that you will have more success once you begin using the methods that return milliseconds.

Comment: The equation seemed to have worked in my console. ` Difference in days:  272`
I used the date 4/4/2021.

Comment: Here's a small function I use occassionally: `function DiffInDays(Day1,Day2) {
  if(Day1 && Day2 && (Object.prototype.toString.call(Day1) === '[object Date]') && (Object.prototype.toString.call(Day2) === '[object Date]')) {
    var day=86400000;
    var t1=new Date(Day1).valueOf();
    var t2=new Date(Day2).valueOf();
    var d=Math.abs(t2-t1);
    var days=Math.floor(d/day); 
    //Logger.log(days);
    return days;
  } else {
    throw 'Invalid Inputs';
  }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is close to what you wish:

```
function myfunk101() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0')
  var rg = sh.getRange("E2:J10");
  var vs = rg.getValues();
  vs.forEach((r,i) =>{
    var r = vs[i];
    if (r[1] == "Backlog") {
      var now = new Date().valueOf();
      var dateOfTask = new Date(r[5]).valueOf();
      var diff = now - dateOfTask;
      var days = Math.floor(diff / 86400000);
      if (days > 14) {
        sh.getRange(i + 2,6).setValue("clear contents");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: The code executes, but no value or string appears in any cells in the range.

Comment: Sorry I was modifying column2 not the second column of your range.

Comment: It worked; thank you, Cooper! I just had to change the column number from a 7 to a 6 - all the credit to you :)